# Dummy Request from Postman to my passkit Wallet API

Tags: ios, postman, applepay, wallet, passkit

Im working on passkit response back API (IOS Wallet). When my targeted clients downloads my coupon apple wallet will hit my API with some data for example: `/v1/devices/{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber}`

That i stores in my database after some business logic.

to test my business logic i have to download my wallet card and delete again & again for testing. i was thinking if i can use POSTMAN instead of iphone it will save time.

Is there a way to send request from postman to my Apple wallet Passkit API.
for my development purposes. Right now, im deleting my coupon card every time to regenerate my request, still i need some more debugging code for example i want to dump some variable to see weather my data coming or no.

any help will make my life little easy.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify the question more. It's difficult to understand what you're actually doing. Those are just request headers and not really helpful. You can "dump some variables" easily enough, if you can show what you response looks look.

Comment: thanks for response just updated my post hope it will give little clear picture.

Comment: Do you need a way of changing the variables on the request? You can use an environment file if that’s what you need. You could also save the response in that file so that you can check the data coming through.

Comment: thanks for response @DannyDainto, im looking help.  how can i send request what  variables required. when im sending post request im not getting same response what im getting from iphone wallet card app.

Comment: I developed Apple Wallet API recently and I had no problems using Postman to test it.
Apple requires several different methods you implement. Different methods require different parameters, eg. Device registration requires Authorization and content-type (application/json) headers and json payload with push token. What type of request is this?
I was using also sample code (Ruby) that Apple granted for Wallet API development. All required are here: https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/Wallet_Support_Materials/WalletCompanionFiles.zip

Comment: @soshman thanks for you response could you share sample code link let me compare what im doing wrong. one last question when you are update pass when your API get pass request. how your api pushing new changes streaming ?

Comment: @M.A Last comment contains link where you can download sample code. It is provided by Apple and it contains all you need to Wallet API.
You should read again Wallet guide by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1 All information you need is there.
About updating a pass - you send whole new Wallet Pass file. Wallet is responsible for comparing old pass with the new one.